# how to keep a button to previous position after drag and drop in android

Tags: android, button, drag-and-drop, android-linearlayout, android-gridlayout

In my android application i have a gridlayout and within it five linearlayout. Four linearlayout contain one button each and another linearlayout is empty. I want to drop a button to the empty linearlayout and when the linearlayout is not empty then after dropping it will take its previous linearlayout position. Using this code

```
 ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();    
 LinearLayout pastContainer = (LinearLayout) owner;
```

i get the linearlayout to which i want to keep my button if target linearlayout is not empty(have child). I get child of target linearlayout to check is it empty using this code

```
LinearLayout newcontainer = (LinearLayout) v;
int count = newcontainer.getChildCount();
```

I can drop a button to a empty linearlayout but when i try to drop a button to a linearlayout with child it gives error. Here is my code

```
private class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) 
    {
        int action = event.getAction();
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // Do nothing
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent(); 
            LinearLayout pastContainer = (LinearLayout) owner;
            LinearLayout newcontainer = (LinearLayout) v;
            int count = newcontainer.getChildCount();                           

            if(count==0)
            {
                owner.removeView(view);     
                newcontainer.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else
            {
                pastContainer.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
          default:
            break;
          }
          return true;
    }             
}
```

how can i keep the button to previous linearlayout if target linearlayout is not empty(have child)? Thanks